# Unexpected error occurred in http client. org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Unbuffered entity enclosing request can not be repeated

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm doing some work with Apache's HttpClient, and see this error:

> Unexpected error occurred in http client. 
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: Unbuffered entity
>   enclosing request can not be repeated.

Any idea what's causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my situation, this meant I was trying to connect to a server that only really supported http using https.

So check if you're using `https` when you should really be using `http`

INFO  qtp1765745171-29 - POST /test 2016-02-18 14:16:50,708

[SENDING] POST **https**://localhost:8080/testpage

or, it could mean that you have a proxy server in front of your https server that's still sending a response, but in http not https